# Equivalent of Convert varbinary in PostgreSQL for bytea

Tags: sql, postgresql, bytea

What is the equivalent of Convert `varbinary` in PostgreSQL for `bytea`? Here's a SQL Server example:

```
CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), 0x5DCC4B0E40401084E1BBF4DA09AC6D24561E07681433310CA3111177D75612CBFFABA42E7276958C4FBF09C5247EA6880CB845F8618063B17EFA986BE5CE87B1E4BAC0B2616AA0EED0496E7B23BA8AC1F85A40ABB55B1C1A09D6413FAB94EE07)
```

Is there a function in PostgreSQL that does the same thing as Convert in `SQL Server` for `bytea`?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the function Decode(). Need to remove the prefix "0x"

```
decode('5DCC4B0E40401084E1BBF4DA09AC6D24561E07681433310CA3111177D75612CBFFABA42E7276958C4FBF09C5247EA6880CB845F8618063B17EFA986BE5CE87B1E4BAC0B2616AA0EED0496E7B23BA8AC1F85A40ABB55B1C1A09D6413FAB94EE07', 'hex')
```